# Nginx proxy_pass changes behavior when defining the target in a variable

Tags: nginx, aws-api-gateway

I'm reverse proxying an AWS API Gateway stage using nginx. This is pretty straightforward:

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:443/production;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}
```

However, this approach will make nginx serve a stale upstream when the DNS entry for `xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` changes as it's resolving the entry once on startup.

Following this article: https://www.nginx.com/blog/dns-service-discovery-nginx-plus/ I am now trying to define my proxy target in a variable like this:

```
location /api {
    set $apigateway xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/production;
    proxy_pass https://$apigateway:443/;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}
```

This will make API Gateway respond with a `ForbiddenException: Forbidden` to requests that would pass the previous setup without using a variable. Reading this document: https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden/ it tells me this could be either WAF filtering my request (when WAF is not enabled for that API) or it could be a missing host header for a private API (when the API is public).

I think I might be doing one these things wrong:

1. The syntax used for setting the variable is wrong
2. Using the variable will make nginx send different headers to API Gateway and I need to intervene manually. I did try setting a `Host` header already, but it did not make any difference though.

The nginx version in use is 1.17.3

Comment: I believe the issue is related to [this nginx ticket](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/803) and [this commit](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/changeset/a108f1ff1690f54051c03bd5c35378d0fdffdcea/nginx_org).  Essentially, if you use a variable with proxy_pass then it will ignore the behavior of a trailing backslash.  The only way around it seems to be to use a URL rewrite like the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the URI `/production` embedded in the variable, so the `:443` is tagged on to the end of the URI rather than the host name. I'm not convinced you need the `:443`, being the default port for `https`.

Also, when variables are used in proxy_pass and a URI is specified in the directive, it is passed to the server as is, replacing the original request URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

You should use `rewrite...break` to change the URI and remove any optional URI from the `proxy_pass` statement.

For example:

```
location /api {
    set $apigateway xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com;
    rewrite ^/api(.*)$ /production$1 break;
    proxy_pass https://$apigateway;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}
```

Also, you will need a `resolver` statement somewhere in your configuration.

Comment: "I'm not convinced you need the :443" - I don't fully understand why either, but API Gateway won't answer unless I specify the port like this. Rewriting manually and omitting the path in the `proxy_pass` directive worked perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a false positive at WAF. Did you try to disable AWS WAF https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/remove-protection.html ?